# Поле RegexField

Tags: django

Создал поле формы

```
reg = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[а-я]{4}$')
```

Но могу вводить любые символы. Почему оно не реагирует на шаблон?

Comment: Может быть регулярное выражение неправильно написали.

Comment: вводить то может и можете, а сохранить не пробовали?

Comment: `form.is_valid()` вызвать?